# C# Event DateTimePicker Conditions

Tags: c#, winforms, events

But I think I’vent really detailed my problem enough. In fact the objective of my program is to offer at the user a tool's software who search some specialized sheet based on different criteria (textbox,combobox,DataTimePicker ...) And my program is based on conditions/ Example:

```
if ( TextBox = " 2")
{
    sqL ? select etc....
}
```

And i want to creat another "else if" to use the datapicker and his value.. I don't know if is really explicit?

Thanks for the help

Comment: That's not how [Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/) work. Based on what you wrote, I think you want to handle the ValueChanged events and then track from there if the value has changed in a different variable

Comment: Exactly this is my problem

Answer (score 2):

`Event` can't be used in conditions, it does not return `bool` required for `if-statement`. `Events` are for **subscribing**.

You can't do:

```
if (dateTimePicker1.ValueChanged)
{
    Foo();
}
else if (dateTimePicker2.ValueChanged)
{
    Bar();
}
```

But you can:

```
dateTimePicker1.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => Foo();
dateTimePicker2.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => Bar();
```